# pass data in one function to another function inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a React component that returns a table with data.

I also use a React Portal to open a new Div on top of the table.

I want to pass data that is in the table to the React Portal.

In the code below, you can see that the portal is called MyPortal and the table is called ResearchTable.

The data that is displayed in the table is called 'data' and in this example, I am show 'data.astronomyTitle' in the table.

I also want to show 'data.astronomyTitle' in the React Portal that pops up.

But I can't figure out how to access 'data' in my MyPortal part of the code because 'data' is only in the Table part.

So my question is, is there any way to pass the data to MyPortal? Or maybe save it in a global variable that can then be accessed by MyPortal?

Thanks!

```
const MyPortal = ({ children }) => (

    ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div id="portal_GalaxyDetails">
            {children}
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('portal-root'),
    )
)

function ResearchTable() {
const [isShown, setIsShown] = React.useState(false);
const hide = () => setIsShown(false);
const show = () => setIsShown(true);

{
    Header: 'Research Opportunities',
    columns: [
        {
         id: <td>{data.astroId}</td>
        },

        {
         title: <td><a href="#" onClick={show}>{data.astronomyTitle}</a></td>
        }
    ]

    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
    galaxyData().then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
    });
}, []);

return (
    <div id="mainContent">
        <table>
            <tr>
                {columns}
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    {isShown && (
        <MyPortal>
            <p>This is my portal</p>
            <button onClick={hide}>Close</button>
        </MyPortal>
    )}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the data to the portal as a prop i.e.

```
<MyPortal astroId={data.astroId}>
  <p>This is my portal</p>
  <button onClick={hide}>Close</button>
</MyPortal>
```

and then make sure you're picking the props up in the Portal component:

```
const MyPortal = ({ astroId, children }) => (

    ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div id="portal_GalaxyDetails">
            <p>{astroId}</p>
            {children}
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('portal-root'),
    )
)
```

Comment: The problem is, {data} is only accessible in my function ResearchTable().  So I need to somehow pass the data from the ResearchTable() to the MyPortal()

Comment: why not put all of this inside a component so that your data is accessible to everything inside that component. Your current `return` can be the render function of your component and you can retrieve the data that your getting inside your function inside the component too